# How to style PHP echo output with span

Tags: php, sql, css, html

I'm trying to style the output of each echo.

Ideally I'd like to use `<span class=""> </span>` for each echo, but I'm not too sure how to achieve this.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blog");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['Date'];
    echo $row['Title'];
    echo $row['Message'];
    echo "<img src='".$row['Image']."'/>";
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: If possible install Xdebug and it will provide a styled output for `var_dump`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blog");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<span class=\"myclass\">$row['Date']</span>";
    echo "<span class=\"myclass\">$row['Title']</span>";
    echo "<span class=\"myclass\">$row['Message']</span>";
    echo "<img src='".$row['Image']."'/>";
    }

mysql_close($con);
```

or, much nicer, in a table:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blog");
echo "<table>"
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<td>$row['Date']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['Title']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['Message']</td>";
    echo "<td><img src='".$row['Image']."'/></td>";
    echo "</tr>"
}
echo "</table>"

mysql_close($con);
```

You then can style each row and column with a class.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$prepend = "<span class=''>";
$append  = "</span>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blog");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo $prepend.$row['Date'].$append;
    echo $prepend.$row['Title'].$append;
    echo $prepend. $row['Message'].$append;
    echo $prepend."<img src='".$row['Image']."'/>".$append;
    }

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd create a function that does this:

```
function decorated_echo($text) {
    echo '<span class="myclass">' . $text . '</span>';
}
```

This way, you don't have to repeat this everytime you want this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You are guessing right, just add required html in the echo:

```
echo '<span class="yourclass"><img src="'.$row['Image'].'" /></span>';
```

or you can just put inline style if no css file is loaded:

```
echo '<span style="color:red;"><img src="'.$row['Image'].'" /></span>';
```