# Can span tag with styling used with echo in php?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to give style in my echo tag in php
for example
**echo 'hello world';**

if i want the text to be bold or color yellow so how do i give style to this?
Ans me the right solution not the shortcut 
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style PHP echo output with span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210552/how-to-style-php-echo-output-with-span)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<span style="font-weight: bold; color: yellow;">hello world</span>';
```

Comment: the styling is applied 
but **text-align:center** is not applying?

Comment: You need to use `div` instead of `span`. `text-align:center` won't work with span.

Comment: so how i do it with span tag?

Comment: The <span> Element is, by default, an "inline" element. Meaning unlike block level elements (<div> <h1> <p> etc.) the span only takes up as much horizontal space as its content.

text-align: center IS working, but you're applying it to an element that doesn't have a width greater than its content (as all block elements do).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<?php echo '<span class="heading">Hello World!</span>' ?>

<style>
 .heading{color:red;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the HTML according to your requirements.

For e.g.

```
echo "<b>Hello World</b>"; // Bold text
echo "<i>Hello World</i>"; //Italics text

echo "<div style='text-color:blue;'>Hello World</div>" ; //Blue colored text
```

There are many other ways you can thave this. Try to generate the correct HTML and CSS.